# Readonly text box showing validation for Regex in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having textbox which is readonly but still showing Regex validation.How to remove Regex validation for readonly textbox.

Here is my Model

```
public FormModel()
{
  public string Area { get; set; }

  [RegularExpressionLocalized("Name", "Name_RE")]
  [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessageResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Name_RF")]
  [DisplayName("Full Name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

HTML for my View

```
 <tr>
   <td class="fieldNameLayoutWidth">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
   </td>
   <td class="fieldControlLayoutWidth">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { size = 40, Title = ToolTips.Name, @readonly = true, 
       Class = "text-field" })
   </td>
 </tr>
```

Even for readonly field,the textbox shows regex validation message with redborder around the textbox.

Please let me know how to remove Regex validation for readonly textbox on load and even when clicking the submit button as it is readonly input.